# If $a^n+n^b\mid c^n+n^d$ for every $n$ then $c=a^k$ and $d=kb$ .

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, perfect-powers

I made a generalization of the following problem (it's a problem from the IMO shortlist in some year) :

> Let $a,b$ be fixed positive integers . If : $$a^n+n \mid b^n+n$$ for every positive integer $n$ then prove that $a=b$ .

This is the generalization :

> Let $a,b,c,d$ be fixed positive integers . If : $$a^n+n^b \mid c^n+n^d$$ for every $n$ then prove that $c=a^k$ and $d=kb$ for some positive integer $k$ odd .

I haven't managed to solve it so this is why I'm looking here for help .Thank you all .

**EDIT**: 
I originally asked to prove that only when $a=c$ and $b=d$ it is possible but thanks to the comments below there are other cases when the divisibility holds .

The problem is now to show that these are the only cases that work .

Comment: Take $a=b=c=1,d=3$, then $1+n\vert1+n^3$ for all n. So you'll need to tighten up your constraints on $a,b,c,d$ (assuming that some form of this is true).

Comment: If $a=b=c=1$ and $d=3$...

Comment: Wow . You're so quick . I'll change it to $a>1$ . Thank you ,both .

Comment: More generally, if $d$ is odd and $c=a^d$ and $b=1$ then $n+a^n$ is divisor of $n^d+(a^n)^d=c^n+n^d$. You need $b>1$. @ComplexPhi

Comment: @πr8 if $a=b=c=1$ $d$ can be any odd integer greater then or equal 3

Comment: For example, $2^n+n$ is always a divisor of $8^n+n^3$.

Comment: So the problems happen when $c=a^x$ and $d=bx$ . Let me think of a way to fix this .

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  I edited the question . Thanks for your counter-examples .

Comment: @ComplexPhi, can you tell which years IMO shortlist question is that or where i can find the solution to that shortlist problem?

Comment: @MosBlack It's from the 2005 SL problem N6 . Here's a link : http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h81371p466215

Comment: @ComplexPhi thanks man!

Comment: The proof appears to be much easier when $a^n-n^b$ divides $c^n-n^d$. It is irritating that such a small change would effect the proof so much.